# Application crashing after an attempt to delete row from UITableView

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.effectsTableView beginUpdates];

        Effect *effectToBeDeleted =self.effectsArray[indexPath.row];
        [self deleteEffectWithName:effectToBeDeleted.name];

        [self.effectsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [self.effectsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.effectsTableView endUpdates];
    }
}
```

The above function should in theory delete the rows as they are slided and the delete button is pressed. However the row does not delete instead is visible even after the

`[self.effectsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];`

is called. And after the user scrolls to the bottom of the UITableView, while loading the last row, the app obviously crashes with `"*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9 beyond bounds [0 .. 8]"` error since one of the objects has been deleted from the array.

the cellForRowAtIndexPath is as follows:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.effectsArray)
    {
        [self loadEffectsInArray];
    }

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"EffectsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }


    Effect *effectCellEffect = [self.effectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *effectCellText = effectCellEffect.name;
    [cell.textLabel setText:effectCellText];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];

    return cell;
}
```

Below is the entire .m file for better context:

```
#import "EffectsManagementTableViewController.h"
#import "Effect+Manage.h"
#import "VLOGAppDelegate.h"
#import "AddEffectViewController.h"
#import "EffectFilterProperty+Manage.h"
#import "Effect.h"

@interface EffectsManagementTableViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *effectsTableView;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSManagedObjectContext *managedObjectContext;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *effectsArray;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *currSelectedRowTitle;

@end

@implementation EffectsManagementTableViewController

-(NSString *)currSelectedRowTitle
{
    if(!_currSelectedRowTitle)
    {
        _currSelectedRowTitle = @"";
    }
    return _currSelectedRowTitle;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;

    VLOGAppDelegate* appDelegate = [UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    self.managedObjectContext = appDelegate.managedObjectContext;
    self.effectsTableView.dataSource = self;
    self.effectsTableView.delegate = self;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [self loadEffectsInArray];
    [self.effectsTableView reloadData];
    [self.effectsTableView setNeedsDisplay];
    [self.effectsTableView setNeedsLayout];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - Table view data source

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (!self.effectsArray)
    {
        [self loadEffectsInArray];
    }
    return [self.effectsArray count];
}

//4
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (!self.effectsArray)
    {
        [self loadEffectsInArray];
    }

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"EffectsCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }

    //6
    Effect *effectCellEffect = [self.effectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *effectCellText = effectCellEffect.name;
    //7
    [cell.textLabel setText:effectCellText];
    //[cell.detailTextLabel setText:@"5 stars!"];
    cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:[UIFont labelFontSize]];
    //cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    //cell.detailTextLabel.textColor = [UIColor grayColor];
    //cell.textLabel.highlightedTextColor = self.effectsTableView.tintColor;

    return cell;
}

- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Return YES if you want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}

// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.effectsTableView beginUpdates];

        Effect *effectToBeDeleted =self.effectsArray[indexPath.row];
        [self deleteEffectWithName:effectToBeDeleted.name];

        [self.effectsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];
        [self.effectsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];


        //[self loadEffectsInArray];
        [self.effectsTableView endUpdates];
        //[self.effectsTableView reloadData];
        //[self.effectsTableView setNeedsLayout];
        //[self.effectsTableView setNeedsDisplay];
    }
}

-(void)deleteEffectWithName:(NSString *)effectName
{
    NSArray *efpForEffectToBeDeleted = [EffectFilterProperty getEffectFilterPropertiesForEffectName:effectName forImmediateEngagement:NO forManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    Effect *effectToBeDeleted = [Effect getEffectWithName:effectName forManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    for (int i = 0; i < efpForEffectToBeDeleted.count; i++)
    {
        EffectFilterProperty *currEFP = efpForEffectToBeDeleted[i];
        currEFP.relatedEffect = nil;
        currEFP.relatedFilterProperty = nil;
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:currEFP];
    }

    [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:effectToBeDeleted];

    NSError *err = nil;
    [self.managedObjectContext save:&err];
    if (err != nil) {
        //Problem while saving
    }
}

-(void)loadEffectsInArray
{
    self.effectsArray = [[Effect getAllEffectsForManagedObjectContext:_managedObjectContext] mutableCopy];
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    Effect *effectCellEffect = [self.effectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    self.currSelectedRowTitle = effectCellEffect.name;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"PushedByTableView" sender:self];
}

/*
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:<#@"reuseIdentifier"#> forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...

    return cell;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional editing of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the specified item to be editable.
    return YES;
}
*/

/*
// Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    } else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
*/

/*
// Override to support rearranging the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
}
*/

/*
// Override to support conditional rearranging of the table view.
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canMoveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Return NO if you do not want the item to be re-orderable.
    return YES;
}
*/


#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    // Make sure your segue name in storyboard is the same as this line
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"PushedByTableView"])
    {
        AddEffectViewController *destinationViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
        NSString *selectedRowText = self.currSelectedRowTitle;
        destinationViewController.effectToManage = [Effect getEffectWithName:selectedRowText forManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
    }
}


@end
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Please check the count of `self.effectsArray`.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the array... It has the amount of rows i want. The only problem is the row doesn't go away even after the above code is executed.

Comment: Did you tried the @Charan sir solution?

Comment: therefore a mismatch occurs between the no. of rows/objects in UITableView and that in the NSMutableArray.

Comment: @iDeveloper yes, didn't work.

Comment: first delete the object from dataSource array and then delete the tableview cell.

Answer (score 3):

where are you beginning your updates, please add

```
[self.effectsTableView beginUpdates];
```

before deleting your row and no need of reloading the table when you are writing the begin updates and end updates.

Please don't remove the object from array before deleting the row.

Comment: At first I had done exactly that... but i think this begin updates might work.

Comment: I put the begin updates at the top of the method. Doesn't work :(

Comment: and have you removed reloadData also

Comment: I just commented it and ran the app... still the same. :|

Comment: and the third one, i told you to not to remove the object from array before deleting the row, is it done in the same way?

Comment: yeah i swapped the two lines.

Comment: and what is the need of array with objects when you have only one object use -> [self.effectsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop]

Comment: no use. just that the parameter accepts arrays only.

Comment: Then the final thing now i gotta know is about your array. There is a problem in your array.

Comment: It is an MSMutableArray with "Effect" objects. Effect is a core data entity. I load it in the [self loadEffectsInArray] method. Which is also called at viewdidload and viewdidappear.

Comment: I am adding the code for cellForRowAtIndexPath in original question.

Comment: Problem not yet solved but I +1'd your answer since it did refine my code a bit :)

Comment: I can't guess the solution anymore until and unless i have your code with me dude.

Comment: wait i'll post the entire .m file in the question

Comment: Don't write all the other stuff inside begin and end updates, only deletion of your row should be inside it.

Comment: sorry bro, it didn't. I can't understand why it won't work. I've invested days into this nonsensical problem with no avail.

Is there a property that needs to be set on the storyboard to enable rows dissapearing? That is the only thing I haven't gone into yet.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/50609/discussion-between-charan-and-aviral-bajpai)

Answer (score 2):

IT'S WORKING
At end of your commitEditingStyle method add this line this will help you

```
[TableViewForFirstView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code to add `beginUpdates`method before delete called

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
      [self.effectsTableView beginUpdates];
        Effect *effectToBeDeleted =self.effectsArray[indexPath.row];
        [self deleteEffectWithName:effectToBeDeleted.name];

        [self.effectsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationTop];

        [self.effectsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self loadEffectsInArray];
        [self.effectsTableView endUpdates];

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    Effect *effectToBeDeleted =[self.effectsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self deleteEffectWithName:effectToBeDeleted.name];
    [self.effectsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self loadEffectsInArray];
    [self.effectsTableView reloadData];

}
```

Comment: there was no change. The row is not being deleted from the UITableView. The array object is being deleted. Therefore the mismatch.

Answer (score 0):

As this message, it's crash for reason out of bound, so try check the array index before assign:

```
Effect *effectToBeDeleted = self.effectsArray > indexPath.row ? self.effectsArray[indexPath.row] : nil;
```

And

```
if(self.effectsArray.count > indexpath.row)
 [self.effectsArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
else
 NSlog("out of bound");
```

Comment: actually the out of bounds is expected, as you might understand, the UITableView is loaded from the effectsArray, whenever a row goes out of the screen and comes back again, the UITableView calls the cellForRowAtIndexPath method to get the title and everything. Now what happens here is the deleted row in the array reduces an object from the array BUT the row in UITableView for some reason is not going away. THAT is the problem.